# SonarQube scanner for MSBuild searches for a type under wrong assembly

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm having a weird error with the SonarQube scanner for MSBuild (scanning C# code).

When running the tool on my project, i am getting this error:

```
"D:\Repro\Buggy.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"D:\Repro\Buggy.Editor.csproj" (Rebuild target) (3) ->
(RunCodeAnalysis target) ->
  MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : Could not find type 'UnityEngine.UI.Selectable' in assembly 'UnityEditor.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'. [D:\Repro\Buggy.Editor.csproj]

    2 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Note that i was able to create a minimal "repro" project that demonstrates this error (found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31384095/Bugs/SonarQube/bug.zip)).

It's hard to tell why running MSBuild would attempt to look for the type named "UnityEngine.UI.Selectable" under that assembly (this type exists, but in a different assembly).

The .sln file i am scanning contains 2 projects (one references the other).

How can i find out what's going on here? and whether this is a bug in the scanner or with how i am using the tool ?

Comment: Just to be sure: no errors if compiling in Visual Studio?

Comment: No errors if building in VS or from MSBuild (without sonar)

Comment: Ever figure out what was going on here or find a solution/workaround? I am getting the same problem with Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: yes, i will post an answer now

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find what was causing this issue.

Running using the latest C# plugin version (5.5.1.522), analysis still fails with the same error.

I also tried running analysis from VS2015 - failed with the same error message.

Digging even deeper - the offending assembly UnityEditor.UI.dll originally references the required UnityEngine.UI.dll, but somehow gets processed to strip that assembly reference.

This is the reason for failure. When executing the analysis, the "tampered" or modified DLL is used.

See more info on this thread i just created: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unityeditor-ui-dll-is-tampered-with-before-copying-to-library-unityassemblies.446053/

I reverted the DLL to the original version and everything works correctly.
So, not a SonarQube bug, but still annoying (and strange!)

This processing of the assemblies is done I believe by VSTU (Visual Studio Tools for Unity), and i also contacted one of the devs on that project - [Jb Evain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36702/jb-evain), currently waiting for a fix).